# Webform, creating customized directories for uploaded files

Tags: webforms, tokens, files

Newbie and my first question on here. I'm still learning Drupal. So apologies if I missed anything

Here is my issue
I am using Webform to create an upload page. The user enters an ID(text field) and uploads the file. The file gets uploaded to a private section on the server. Now I am trying to make sure that the file gets uploaded into this separate folder(named after the ID)( say all/private/ID/). Can I do that using a Webform ? For now, all I can use are basic tokens,not values I can grab from other fields(ex: %username) to create these directories.

If webforms are not the answer, what else would be a good method to go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greetings welcome to the land of Drupal stuff :)

In general here are some tips:

- creating a folder off of a textfield `ID` is going to be cumbersome. How will you know subsequent users aren't putting in the same `ID` and or overwriting eachothers files?
- [Webform has an API of available hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/group/webform_hooks/7). For instance look at [webform_submission_presave()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7) which allows you to change/capture a users submitted answer and alter it; you could likely alter the destination of the file to be saved, and assure the destination directory exists with a Drupal API function [file_prepare_directory](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_prepare_directory/7).

If you're looking for an all-in-one no code solution. Look at this issue queue [PATCH for webform that looks like it supports custom tokens for upload files](https://drupal.org/node/326738).

Comment: Thank your the suggestions.(Appreciate the warm welcome too). I will take a look into them.  


I've already looked at the patch you linked to. From what I understand, the custom token support is ust limited to pre-existing basic tokens. The patch creates a directory as soon as you define it, so the tokens will already have to be predefined and existing before you can use it(So %useremail works but %post[key] does not work, it only creates a directory of the same name).