# How can one automatically rename files uploaded in a webform?

Tags: webforms

I would like to rename the files uploaded to a webform according to some tokens or the value in some other field.

I did some research on this and was surprised to find no definite solution.

For example:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/326738 => A patch supplied for token support but the discussion ends without a final working patch
- https://www.drupal.org/node/364752 => Discussion on "Renaming file upload fields using other form fields". Discussion ends in "Won't Fix"
- [Webform, creating customized directories for uploaded files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79946/webform-creating-customized-directories-for-uploaded-files) => Approaches have been suggested here but no final solution given.

Comment: I'm 1 of the approved answers in your post. I understand your concern. I recommend making a small module or attempt to provide this new functionality in a patch to close existing issue(s) for webform. You should realize webform was born very separate from drupal -- hence all these types of integration issues that when using other modules, fields or Views we never face. If it was super easy -- it'd already be done. Webform is a big module with alot of legacy functionality.

Comment: Yes, tenken. You have certainly provided a good answer on that post but I wish there was a solution somewhere. Anyways, I will hook into webform and post my solution here. One final solution.

Comment: @AyeshK https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/developermitesh/2384305 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2139287 and https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/thsutton/2231145

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox project is removed as the issue queue get continued, the latest patch has been failed in simpletest, but you can still [check this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2139287#comment-9596553)

Answer (score 1):

You can change every file upload by [hook_file_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7) as your desire pattern
as example

```
function yourmodulename_file_presave($file) {
  $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
  $file->filename = 'mypattern_'.$file->uid .'_'. $file->timestamp . '.' . $parts['extension'];
}
```

**but this method do not rename filname(it just rename file name in file_managed table),** if you want also rename file name (uri of file) you should use below code

```
function yourmodulename_file_insert($file) {
  $parts = pathinfo($file->filename);
  $uri = 'public://'.'mypattern_'.$file->uid .'_'. $file->timestamp . '.' . $parts['extension'];
  $file=file_move($file, $uri);
}
```